# CKEditor this.editables is not availble during a downcast?

Tags: widget, ckeditor, downcast

This is an extract of my plugin ([full version](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/scald/tree/modules/fields/mee/plugins/dndck4/plugin.js?id=51aa96d9cf5ae05a09667851b3e86489ada4b052)):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('dndck4', {
  lang: 'en',
  requires: 'widget',

  init: function (editor) {
    editor.widgets.add('dndck4', {
      dialog: 'atomProperties',
      pathName: 'atom',
      editables: {
        caption: {
          selector: '.dnd-caption-wrapper',
          pathName: 'caption',
          allowedContent: 'a[href]; strong; em'
        }
      },
...
      downcast: function(el) {
        var caption = '';
        if (this.data.usesCaption) {
          caption = this.editables.caption.getHtml();
        }
        var html = Drupal.dndck4.downcastedHtml(this.data, caption);
        return CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromHtml(html);
      },
```

It worked well, until another JS does something apparently [harmless](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/yoast_seo/tree/js/yoast_seo.js?id=b2351c585714283a65936606f7ed197d62341e9a#n96):

```
  editor.on('change', function() {
    // Let CKEditor handle updating the linked text element.
    editor.updateElement();
  });
```

It breaks my widget based plugin (this.editables is an empty object). Of course I can just check this.editables to avoid error in the next line `caption = this.editables.caption.getHtml();` but I'd like to know what happened and why.

Comment: What is the `editor.updateElement` do?

Comment: @MarekLewandowski I updated the question to include the link to the full code. editor.updateElement() is supposed to update the textarea with the changed content from CKEditor, so that behind Yoast SEO can process the content of the textarea.

Comment: And without this `change` listener you don't experience this problem?

Comment: No problem without that listener (or precisely, without the `editor.updateElement()` line).